# SaveFileDialog Filter shows .xlsx Links?

Tags: c#, excel, filter, xlsx, savefiledialog

I want to open a SaveFileDialog and Filter for example .tgz Files. Here is my Code:

```
string dummyFileName = "file.tgz";
string savePath = "fail";
SaveFileDialog sf = new SaveFileDialog();
//Feed dummy name to the save dialog
sf.FileName = dummyFileName;
sf.Filter = ".tar.gz|*.tgz";
if (sf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Now here's our save folder
    savePath = Path.GetFullPath(sf.FileName);
}
// then i check if savePath = "fail", in case the user abborted it, and return.
```

The Filter works. I also changed it to .txt or .exe but what I noticed: I have some Links to .xlsx Files on my Desktop which are shown. The actual Files are not shown, only the Links from Excel Files! Did anybody else noticed that and got a workaround?

The Problem is, I want to use this Filename afterwards. When the User now clicks on the Link, it changes the Filename.

Comment: I see it.  Awkward Windows behavior, might have something to do with a shell extension that Office installs, but that's just a guess.  There isn't much you can do about, you can't mess with the user's machine.  If you absolutely want to prevent the user from selecting the wrong file, not so sure that's necessary, then you'll have to double-check the filename extension.  You can do so in an event handler for the FileOk event.

Comment: you have the same Problem? awkward... No, I can't mess with that. The Problem is that my Code is then going to create a .tgz, or .xlsx file in this case, and is probably going to overwrite the existing one. Just to prevent all this, I would like to not see them at all. The workaround is a good way to prevent that, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to filter what is displayed in the dialog instead of filter with which extension a file is saved as, set the `DefaultExt` property on your `Dialog`:

```
string dummy = "file.tgz";
string path = "";
SaveFileDialog sf = new SaveFileDialog();
sf.FileName = dummy;
sf.DefaultExt = ".tgz"; // <== This one.
sf.Filter = "gzipped tar files (*.tgz)|*.tgz";
if (sf.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    path = sf.FileName;
}
```

This will filter the files being displayed in your `Dialog`.